# How to do a case of 2 parameters in a sql query

Tags: sql

In a query I do :

```
 SUM(CASE kbpres.soort WHEN 'K' THEN kbpres.prijs END) 
                  AS FACKOSTEN
```

but I would like to use something like `WHEN 'K' or WHEN 'V' THEN`
but how do I do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE kbpres.soort WHEN 'K' THEN kbpres.prijs 
                  WHEN 'V' THEN kbpres.prijs
END)
              AS FACKOSTEN
```

OR

```
SUM(CASE WHEN kbpres.soort IN('K', 'V') THEN kbpres.prijs END)
              AS FACKOSTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN kbpres.soort = 'K' OR kbpres.soort = 'V' THEN kbpres.prijs ELSE NULL END
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN kbpres.soort IN ('K', 'V') THEN kbpres.prijs ELSE NULL END
```

Or

```
CASE kbpres.soort WHEN 'K' THEN kbpres.prijs
                  WHEN 'V' THEN kbpres.prijs
                           ELSE NULL
END
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN kbpres.soort = 'K' THEN kbpres.prijs
     WHEN kbpres.soort = 'V' THEN kbpres.prijs
                             ELSE NULL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN kbpres.soort IN ('K', 'V') THEN kbpres.prijs END) 
                  AS FACKOSTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know wich database engine you use, but in MySQL you can write this :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN kbpres.soort = 'K' OR kbpres.soort = 'V' THEN kbpres.prijs END) 
                  AS FACKOSTEN
```

Comment: I'm sorry it is MS SQL SERVER 2008